# Use enums for array indexes in Java

Tags: java, enums

While reading Effective Java I came across the suggestion to "use enums instead of `int` constants". In a current project I am doing something similar to that below:

```
int COL_NAME = 0;
int COL_SURNAME = 1;

table[COL_NAME] = "JONES"
```

How would I use enums instead to achieve this? Due to the interface I'm forced to use, I must use an `int` for my index. The example above is just an example. I'm actually using an API that takes an `int` for index values.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Applying one usefull pattern together with an anti-pattern often fails ;-)

In your case using an array for not-really array-like data provides a problem when you want to replace `int` constants with `enum` values.

A clean(er) solution would be something like an [`EnumMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) with the `enum` values as keys.

Alternatively you could use [`table[COL_NAME.ordinal()]`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal%28%29) if you absolutely must.

If some API forces you to pass around `int` values but you have control over the actual values (i.e. you could pass your own constants), then you could switch to using `enum` values in your code and convert to/from `enum` only at the places where your code interfaces with the API. The reverse operation of `enumValue.ordinal()` is `EnumClass.values()[ordinal]`).

Comment: I believe table[COL_NAM.ordinal()] is what EnumMap does behind the scenes, just more correctly than what one of us is likely to write on the fly.

Comment: @ILMTitan: I agree. I just posted that, since the OP says some API forces him to use arrays.

Comment: I don't agree that this is an anti-pattern.  Other languages DO treat enums as primitives and it makes a lot of sense to have ranges, sub-ranges and arrays over an enum base.  It makes a lot more sense than needing to declare `static final int ... SOMETHING` and write `select(...){ .. }` statements  *imho*.  Second, the fact that we need an `EnumMap` is *prima facie* evidence that something is missing.

Comment: @will: all that it is evidence for is that enums in Java are not the same as enums in other languages. In other languages they are glorified integers and are correctly treated like that. In Java they are not. Applying patterns from other languages blindly can be an anti-pattern.

Comment: I an agree with that, they probably have been misnamed some documentation: [enumerated type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type).  Although someone really ought to look into a PL/1 and ALGOL-68 examples.

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you are trying to use a EnumMap. This is a Map which wraps an array of values.

```
enum Column {
   NAME, SURNAME
}

Map<Column, String> table = new EnumMap<Column, String>(Column.class);

table.put(Column.NAME, "JONES");

String name = table.get(Column.NAME);
```

This would much simpler if you used a POJO.

```
classPerson {
   String name;
   String surname;
}

Person person = new Person();
person.name = "JONES";
String name = person.name;
```

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the requirements. You could use `Enum.ordinal()` to convert an enum to an int.

Note that it's not possible to pass an Enum directly as the index.

Edit:

Another possibility would be to use a `Map<YourEnum, String> map` and then use `map.get(EnumValue)`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have to use that table and thus can't actually use an `EnumMap`, I personally think the best solution would be to stick with what you have. In an enum, the ordinal values of the elements are not supposed to have any intrinsic meaning, while in your case they do, since they are used as indices into the table.

The problem you have is not that you are not using enums, it's that you need magic values to extract column data out of a table. In this case, using integer constants is the right tool for the job, unless if you can tackle the underlying problem of that table.

Now you could tackle it by wrapping the table in your own class that accesses it, and use enums in and out that class. But this introduces more code, another layer of indirection and doesn't actually solve any problems for you, except that an enum is a bit easier to maintain than a list of int values (greatly offset by you having to maintain the wrapper you now wrote).

You could consider this work if you are writing a public API that other people will use, since it will avoid having them depend on some magic values that might change over time (tight coupling which will break things). If you are, then a wrapper which uses an `EnumMap` internally is likely the way to go.

Otherwise, leave it as is.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the values of your array, you might be looking at an object instead. For examples if your array looks something like this

```
person[FIRST_NAME] = "Jim Bob"
person[SURNAME] = "Jones"
person[ADDRESS] = "123 ABC St"
person[CITY] = "Pleasantville"
...
```

Then what you really want is something like this

```
Person jimBob = new Person("Jim Bob", "Jones");
jimBob.setAddress("123 ABC St", "Pleasantville", "SC");
....
```

See [Refactoring: Replace Array with Object](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-array-with-object)

Answer (score 0):

I have also run into this problem, and having come from the C++ world I wasn't expecting to run into this.

The beauty of enum is that can create a series of related constants with unique values where the actual value is irrelevant.  Their use makes code easier to read and guards against variables being set to invalid enum values (especially in Java), but in a situation like this it is a major pain.  While you might have "enum Pets { CAT, BIRD, DOG }" and don't really care what value CAT, BIRD, and DOG actually represent, it's so nice and clean to write: 
    myPets[CAT] = "Dexter"; 
    myPets[BIRD] = "Polly"; 
    MyPets[DOG] = "Boo-Rooh";

In my situation I ended up writing a conversion function where you pass in an enum value and I return a constant.  I hate doing this with a passion, but it's the only clean way I know to maintain the convenience and error checking of enum.

```
private int getPetsValue(Pets inPet) {

    int value = 0; 
    switch (inPet) {

        case CAT:    value = 0;    break;
        case BIRD:   value = 1;    break;
        case DOG:    value = 2;    break;
        default:
            assert(false);
            value = 0;
            break;
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing but it looks like you don't know about `Enum.ordinal()`. IMHO, you'd better don't try to program like Java was C++, it's similar but different, and blindly applying *all* what you're used to is a way to a disaster.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an `enum` with a constructor like so:

```
public enum ArrayIndex {
    COL_NAME(0), COL_SURNAME(1);
    private int index;

    private ArrayIndex(int index) {
    this.index = index;
    }

public int getIndex() {
    return this.index;
}
};
```

And then use it like this:

```
public static void main (String args[]) {
    System.out.println("index of COL_NAME is " + ArrayIndex.COL_NAME.getIndex());
}
```