# how to use an enum as an array index in java

Tags: java, arrays, enums

I'm storing 12 values in an array and each one represents a piece of data for a certain month. I have an enum for all the months of the year and would like to be able to choose a month that displays the correct data instead of using the array index. Is there a way to do this? Thanks

Comment: if ( month == Month.JANUARY ){ index = 0;} ...

Comment: May be duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417454/use-enums-for-array-indexes-in-java

Comment: You can either use 12 disgusting `if/else if` blocks, or a Map. I recommend the latter.

Answer (score 11):

I would recommend against using enum members as array indices because there's the risk that the numeric index of the enum members will change (if new members are added or if the order of the members is changed within the enum class).

Instead I would use a `Map<Month, Data>` so that each enum member points to a `Data` object (or any other type that you need to use) within the map:

```
Map<Month, Data> monthMap = new HashMap<>();
monthMap.put(Month.MARCH, dataObject);
Data retrievedData = monthMap.get(Month.MARCH);
```

**Update**: if your `Map` uses an enum type as its key then it's always more efficient to use an `EnumMap` instead of a `HashMap`, `TreeMap`, etc. So the code above would be better starting off like this:

```
Map<Month, Data> monthMap = new EnumMap<>(Month.class);
```

Behind the scenes, `EnumMap` is in fact maintaining an array whose indices align with the enum instances, exactly as the OP was hoping to achieve manually.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer if OP does not need to use an array

Answer (score 8):

If you have enum of days of week like:

```
public enum Days {
    SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY,
    THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY 
}
```

and arrays like: `String days[]=new String[7]`

The indexing in the array can only be done by `int`.So you can use enum as the indexes as:

```
days[Days.SUNDAY.ordinal()]="sunday";
System.out.println(days[Days.SUNDAY.ordinal()]);
```

`Output:sunday`

`Ordinal()` returns the position of the `enum` constant in the `enum` declaration.
But it does not look so elegant.

Answer (score 2):

so for example you have your enum like:

```
public enum Month {
    January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December
}
```

then you can use `ordinal()` to get a numerical representation (index of you definition).
where `name()` returns you the enum's name

here an example which shows you the useage for both of em:

```
    Month[] months = Month.values();

    Month m = Month.August;
    System.out.println(String.format("Month #%d > %s", m.ordinal(), months[m.ordinal()].name()));
```